# I need to change the href content to # where the REL is tag. Can I do it with jQuery in a wordpress theme?

Tags: jquery, href, rel

Hey guys I need your help.

I need to change the href content to # where the REL of the `<a>` is "tag". Can I do it with jQuery in a wordpress theme?

Thanks

Comment: please share your html code and explain your problem

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the following (assuming there's nothing left out of the question, which I suspect there might be...):

```
$('a[rel="tag"]').attr('href', '#');
```

```js
$('a[rel="tag"]').attr('href', '#');
```

```css
a::after {
  content: ' (attr: ' attr(href)', rel: ' attr(rel)')';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="tag">link1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="notTag">link2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="tag">link3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="something entirely different">link4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="tag">link5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or, without jQuery:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[rel="tag"]'), function (aElement) {
    aElement.setAttribute('href', '#');
});
```

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[rel="tag"]'), function (aElement) {
    aElement.setAttribute('href', '#');
});
```

```css
a::after {
  content: ' (attr: ' attr(href)', rel: ' attr(rel)')';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="tag">link1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="notTag">link2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="tag">link3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="something entirely different">link4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="tag">link5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. This will change all 'a' elements href tag to the google adress.

> $("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")

Toselect only one you should give it an id and change it like this.

> $("#theNameOfYourIdHere").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")